# How to insert UITableView in UINavigationController

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

[image]

I'm making one application.
The App's main view is singleViewController.
After I tap the Label in the singleViewController, the display goes to UINavigationController instance screen (Reference:Captured Image).
Below code is the method, when I tap the label.
Then, what I want to ask is about 
1. what should I do to add UITableView in the UINavigationController ? 
2. And should I prepare for UINavigationController class file(.h and .m)

◆My transition image is below
 [singleViewController(without UINavigationController)] ←→　[UINavigationController(with UITableView)]

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
if ( touch.view.tag == mainCountryLabel.tag ){
    NSLog(@"%d", mainCountryLabel.tag);
    NSLog(@"Label Clicked !!");
    UINavigationController *testView = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    testView.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self presentViewController:testView animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```

Best Regards

Comment: Are you using storyboard?

Comment: >>YuviGr     I won't use storyboard, because I want to understand Objective-c deeply. I think storyboard is useful, but it is not valuable for programmer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest you to initialise `SingleViewController` with `UINavigationController`'s `RootViewController`.

If not, then on button click you are presenting `NavigationContorller` with `UITableView`.
So disable your navigation bar this gap is because of that.

Just use a hidden property, and set it to `YES`.

Comment: Hi, Rinku. I understand your smart advice. I will try it. Thank you very much !!

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is instead of using the default `UINavigationBar` you can use a customized one. You can do `[navController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];` in the `viewWillAppear:` of your controller and add a customized view in place of your navigation controller with the `UITableView` embedded in it. This approach will be easier because you have the freedom of customizing your `UINavigationBar` accordingly.

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you so much, I customized in the point of your idea. But, my image is near Rinku's idea. Anyway, I could get information about it !! Thank you !!

Comment: @tomojiro  Hey that's all right :) And thanks for the upvote :)